# How can I add my application to the android default Call log manager selection?

Tags: android, calllog

I am creating an call log manager app, and I want to make it can act as default android call log manager.

Let's me explain my expectation more clearly.

I want after use make a phone call, system open a chooser dialog which show all apps have same category (etc, call log manager category), and I want my app is one of them. And user can choose my app as a default call log manager. And after that, each time a phone call ended, my app was launched.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance all of you guy!

Answer (score 0):

Intent.ACTION_CALL is paired with some application for example the 'Dialer' app to be the default app that will be started every time the Intent.ACTION_CALL it is raised...

add this to your permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

and code below to your code:

```
String number = "23454568678";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but seem you misunderstood on my question.
I don't want my app act like a dialer, but like a call log manager ( for user can see who called to him/her and who he/she called to). And as finally result, I want my app replace android system's default call log manager (call history).